# Where is the implicit conversion that changes signedness?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, integer, implicit-conversion, size-t

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void someFunction(int number);

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}

void someFunction(int number)
{
  char* string = (char*) malloc((number+1)*sizeof(char));
}
```

When I run it on my computer with the Code::Blocks IDE and the GNU GCC compiler it works without any problems. But when I use it on another machine (also with Code:Blocks and LLVM Clang Compiler compiler) I get the error

> implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long'
> [-Werror,-Wsign-conversion]

This error refers to the line

> char* string = (char*) malloc((number+1)*sizeof(char));

If I get the error message correctly there is some "int" that is implicitly converted to "unsigned long", but I do not see where this happens.

Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: I'd go a step further: Make the argument of `someFunction` already `size_t` – this is the correct type for specifying sizes anyway. Note that with `int` you'd actually have to check for negative values – as these would get converted to huge positive ones, potentially provoking `malloc` to fail.

Comment: Avoid static types as far as possible, by the way. Assume you change `string` from `char` to `wchar_t` – then you have to update the call to malloc as well (and potentially other places) – you automatically get correct size if you write `char* string = malloc((number + 1) * sizeof(*string));`

Comment: @3nondatur After reading the various good answers, continue with `void someFunction(size_t number) { char* string = malloc(sizeof string[0] * (number+1));
}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a warning considered by the compiler as an error due to the compiler options `-Werror` and `-Wsign-conversion`.

Within the expression

```
(number+1)*sizeof(char)
```

used in the call of `malloc` the operand `sizeof( char )` has unsigned integer type `size_t` that is an alias for the type `unsigned long`. On the other hand, the operand `number+1` has the signed type `int`. The rank of the type `size_t` is higher than the rank of the type `int`. It means that due to the usual arithmetic conversions the operand of the type `int` will be implicitly converted to the type `size_t` and thus can lose its sign.

To resolve the problem just declare the function parameter like

```
void someFunction(size_t number);
```

There is no sense to pass a signed value to the function that allocates memory. And moreover the parameter of the function `malloc` has the type `size_t`.

To make it clear then consider the following simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int number = -1;

    printf( "( size_t )number = %zu\n", ( size_t )number );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
( size_t )number = 4294967295
```

As you can see the negative variable `number` of the type `int` converted to the unsigned integer type `size_t` becomes a very big unsigned integer.

Answer (score 4):

The signature of the [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function is

```cpp
void* malloc(size_t size);
```

`size_t` is an **unsigned** integer type, whereas `int` is signed.
You are passing the value `(number+1)*sizeof(char)` to this function.

clang basically asks you: what is gonna happen in this function if the value of `number` passed into it is negative?

To get rid of this, either explicitly cast `number` to a `size_t` to tell the compiler that you know it's not gonna be negative, or change the type of `number` to be `size_t` in the first place.

Also note that this is only an error because clang was called with the `-Werror` flag (treats all warnings as errors). Otherwise this would just be a *warning*, meaning that the program would still compile, but the compiler will inform you about a potential issues.
That is not to say that `-Werror` is a bad idea though, in fact it is recommended practice unless you are doing rapid prototyping.

**Note**: in this specific case, the conversion actually already happens during the *multiplication*. My clang gives the following output:

```cpp
main.c:14:40: error: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Werror,-Wsign-conversion]
  char* string = (char*) malloc((number+1)*sizeof(char));
                                 ~~~~~~^~ ~
```

If you look closely, it underlines `number+1` (operand of type `int`) and `*` (the operator).
The type of `sizeof(char)` is `size_t` (here shown as the equivalent `unsigned long`). So to perform the multiplication, clang already has to convert the types.

Comment: But you should be compiling with `-Werror` so that you don't try running code where the compiler thinks there are (or could be) problems.

Comment: Inasmuch as you seem to be suggesting that the conversion happens to match the argument to the parameter type, no.  If an `int` *were* presented as an argument to `malloc()`, then it *would* be converted to `size_t`, as you say, but that doesn't happen here.  The conversion happens in the expression `(number+1)*sizeof(char)` itself, as the other answer describes.  `number+1` is automatically converted to `size_t` to match the other operand of `*`, and the product is computed as a `size_t`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: good catch. I added a Note. Since `malloc(number)` would cause the same issue though, I think it is still fine to explain the problem from that angle, since it gives a more practical reason for the error message.